# SUM function summing records twice

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

First of all for you to understand my question I need to show you my DB model, so here it is.

[image: DB Model]

Now that you have seen it, here goes my question:

I have this query

```
select SUM(e.totalEtapa) totalProyecto,
    e.idProyecto
from Etapa e
inner join EtapaPartida ep on ep.idEtapa = e.idEtapa
inner join Partida p on p.numero = ep.idPartida
    and p.version = ep.versionPartida
left join Partida b on b.numero = p.numero
    and p.version < b.version
inner join LineaRecursoPartida lrp on p.numero = lrp.numPartida
    and p.version = lrp.versionPartida
inner join LineaRecurso lr on lr.id = lrp.IdLinea
inner join Recurso r on r.codigo = lr.codigo
    and r.version = lr.version
where r.codigo = 2
    and r.version = 2
    and b.version is null
group by e.idProyecto
```

So as you can see, and in relation you the model I show you above, I want the sum of all the records on etapa that are related to a recurso's record taking into account all the join necessary to get to it and that the partida's records should be their "maximun versions", in this case the recurso with codigo = 2 and version = 2. So the thing is this query is returning twice the value that should. Making some research I realized that this is happening because my recurso's record is related to two records on partida's table and likewise this ones are related to the same etapa's record through the EtapaPartida table.

I already tried using the distinct clause, adding the column idEtapa from table Etapa on the above query with no success. Anyway, I don't like to use this kind of clauses to get rid of the problem beacause it may cause another. So I would like to know if any of you have any idea on how just returning one record from etapa not regarding whether are they are related to several partida's record related to the same recurso's record?

Comment: You are joining along different dimensions, so you are getting a Cartesian product for each `idProjecto`.  Aggregate (in subqueries) before doing the joins.

Comment: change it to `select *` and remove the `group by` and you'll see